# ideas on how to reload demo site db daily

Tags: database, grails

I have a demo site where users can log into the site and change pretty much everything, including the page with the instructions on how to log in :)

obviously i cant leave this site up without rebuilding its database now and then, or **ill be linking to goatse** before i know it.

i am open to ideas on the easiest way to do this.

I am running grails which uses hibernate behind the scenes. i wonder if a proc to drop all the tables, and reinsert data will make hibernate throw up.

another option would be to run a quartz job to programatically remove everything and reinsert it, but the problem with that is that its MUCH easier to setup the initial version via the sites admin interface, so id be doing a lot of work via services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your using MySQL set up a job using your operating system's scheduling facilities

to run the mysql client with an sql dump of the state you want to bring the database to every day. I've done this on a grails app and had no problems although your users may run into issues if they try and access the site while the database is being restored. When I've recreated the database from a dump while my grails app was running I had no issues accessing it after the database restore. If your not using mysql the same instructions should apply, you'll just have to use a method specific  to your database. When I did this I did not drop and create the actual database, I just dropped and recreated all the database tables.

Comment: i assume you did mysql -uroot -proot < dump.sql on a cron?

Answer (score 1):

DBUnit - http://dbunit.sourceforge.net/

As your site is in effect a "Test" site, and you want it to revert back to a well known state, it may be the right answer for you.